# UIWebView memory alternatives?

Tags: iphone, memory, uiwebview

I have an app that heavily relies on clicking on links on websites.  It uses one UIView with a web view.  The problem I ran into is that after clicking through a few links, the app will run out of memory and the app will crash.  I've read through tons of posts about UIWebView and its memory issues - are there any alternatives I can use if all I want is to load web pages and capture when people click through links?

Answer (score 1):

Found an awesome alternative!

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

Comment: n/m i think i still get memory issues when loading the html into UIWebView :(